# Are Chromecast Preview SDK app ids good for the newly released final SDK?

Tags: google-cast

Are Preview Chromecast SDK app ids good for the newly released final SDK or should I register a new app on the Google Cast SDK Developer Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not good; you need to re-register your apps and devices but this time, you will do all of that yourself and no email approval, etc is involved. You can also publish your app to the public whenever you decide to do it, so you are totally in charge.